# When using conemu with Windows 10 bash shell, why doesn't the UP key show the previous command?

Tags: windows, bash, conemu

The up arrow scrolls through command history, but it doesn't work after I launch bash shell.

Comment: try using `Ctrl+P` and `Ctrl+N` instead

Comment: I'm not sure yet who (ConEmu of Windows) is responsible for the problem. But the issue has been created: https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/629

Answer (score 17):

Solution for now is to use next command:

```
%windir%\system32\bash.exe -cur_console:p
```

It can be found [here](https://conemu.github.io/en/BashOnWindows.html) on official site.

Worked for me on [Cmder](http://cmder.net/) as well.

Answer (score 5):

Also, here is a config for Cmder to lunch bash.exe with config given by Kostiantyn Korniyenko just in case.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Reading through the discussions [here](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/629). I settled with following value that worked for me

> %windir%\system32\bash.exe ~/mnt/ -l -i -cur_console:p1
>   -new_console:p:n

Answer (score 0):

Set a switch for `-cur_console:p[n]` where `n` is the pty mode:

> p[N] - pty modes, N - bitmask: 1 - XTermKeys, 2 - BrPaste, 4 - AppCursorKeys; default is 1

from https://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html